# Sum with null values in MS Access

Tags: forms, ms-access, null, sum

I have a problem about sum of a value and null values. What I want to achive is having a value as Sum regardless of having null fields. Here is my code in form:

```
Public Sub projectname_Change()

Me.total1_n = DSum("SumBudgeted_amount2", "second_q")
Me.total2_n = DSum("SumBudgeted_amount2", "second_q2")
Me.total3_n = DSum("SumBudgeted_amount2", "second_q3")
Me.total4_n = DSum("SumBudgeted_amount2", "second_q4")
End Sub
```

There are null values second_q areas. Even though one field has a value, because o null values, the program gives error. I tried to add

```
Me.total1_n = DSum("SumBudgeted_amount2", "second_q", [Nz(second_q,[0])])
```

codes at the end of all second_qs and also tried IIf(IsNull... code. However, they did not work. Please help me with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Me.total1_n = DSum("Nz([SumBudgeted_amount2],0)", "second_q")
```

or

```
Me.total1_n = DSum("Nz(SumBudgeted_amount2,0)", "second_q")
```

(the database functions are fussy about the presence, or absence, of square brackets.)

I really don't trust NZ() and always avoid it:

```
Me.total1_n = DSum("IIf(SumBudgeted_amount2 Is Null,0,SumBudgeted_amount2)", "second_q")
```

try with and without square brackets.

Comment: Access gave this error:
    The expression you entered as a query parameter produced this error: '[SumBudgeted_amount2]'

Comment: Is "SumBudgeted_amount2" a field in your table "second_q"? It should be. And what is the full error message.

Comment: "SumBudgeted_amount2" is a field in "second_q" union query. Ful error: Run-time error '2471': The expression you entered as a query parameter produced this error: '[SumBudgeted_amount2]'

Comment: You could try removing the square brackets - the database functions are fussy about these.

Comment: Same error without brackets :/ I will try different combinations of brackets and parenthesis. Thanks for suggestion. Most probably one of your codes will work.

Comment: Well, when I tried **Me.total1_n = DSum("IIf(SumBudgeted_amount2 Is Null,0,SumBudgeted_amount2)", "second_q")** code, it worked. Maybe I just needed sleep to be more careful :) Thanks again